# React Native props (não atualiza lista do flatlist)

Tags: react-native

Bom dia, estou tendo dificuldades em passar uma props pra um componente e receber estes valores novamente. Tenho um componente de busca em que filtro um flatlist. Os itens do flatlist também estão em um componente. Quando efetuo a busca, minha lista do flatlist não é atualizada. Segue os códigos:

HomeScreen

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Alert, FlatList, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import ItemList from '../../components/item-list/ItemList';
import SearchBar from '../../components/search-bar/SearchBar';
import { useTheme } from '../../context/ThemeProvider';
import MyService from '../../services/MyService';
import Styles from './styles';

const HomeScreen = ({navigation}) => {

    const { theme } : any = useTheme();

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getDados();
    }, []);

    async function getDados() {
        try {
            const response = await MyyService.getAllDados();
            setFilteredData(response.data);
            setData(response.data);
        } catch {
            Alert.alert(
                'Erro',
                'Falha ao exibir dados!',
                [{text: 'OK'}]
            );
        }
    }

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={[Styles.container, {backgroundColor: theme.backgroundColor}]}>
            <SearchBar data={data} filteredData={filteredData} />
            <FlatList
                data={filteredData}
                renderItem={({item}) => <ItemList item={item} navigation={navigation} />}
                keyExtractor={(item) => String(item.id)}
            />
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

SearchBar

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';
import { TextInput, View } from 'react-native';
import Styles from './styles';
import { useTheme } from '../../context/ThemeProvider';

const SearchBar = ({data, filteredData}) => {

    const { theme } : any = useTheme();

    const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');
    
    const searchFilter = (text: string) => {
        if(text) {
            const newData = data.filter((item) => {
                return item.nome.toUpperCase().indexOf(text.toUpperCase()) > -1;
            });
            filteredData = newData;
            setSearchText(text);
        } else {
            filteredData = data;
            setSearchText(text);
        }
    }

    return(
        <View style={Styles.searchContainer}>
            <View style={[Styles.inputContainer, {backgroundColor: theme.search.container}]}>
                <Icon
                    name="search"
                    size={20}
                    style={Styles.searchIcon}
                    color={theme.search.placeholder}
                />
                <TextInput 
                    style={[Styles.input, {color: theme.search.textColor}]}
                    placeholder='Pesquise por nome'
                    placeholderTextColor={theme.search.placeholder}
                    value={searchText}
                    onChangeText={(text) => searchFilter(text)}
                />
            </View>
        </View>
    );

};

export default SearchBar;
```

ItemList

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import { useTheme } from '../../context/ThemeProvider';
import Styles from './styles';

const ItemList = ({item, navigation}) => {

    const { theme } : any = useTheme();

    return(
        <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
                navigation ? navigation.navigate('TelaStack', item) : null
            }}>
            <View style={[Styles.container, {borderColor: theme.inactive}]}>
                <Image style={Styles.image} source={require('../../assets/images/user-avatar.png')} />
                <View style={Styles.contentWrapper}>
                    <Text style={[Styles.nome, {color: theme.textColor}]}>{item.nome}</Text>
                    <Text style={{color: theme.inactive}}>{item.fabricante.nome}</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );

};

export default ItemList;
```

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que você está tentando mudar o estado de `filteredData` do `HomeScreen`, dentro do `SearchBar`, e o gerenciamento de estado não funciona dessa forma. Mas existe uma forma de fazer o que você precisa.

Fiz umas pequenas alterações, não testei mas acredito que vá te ajudar.

```
// HomeScreen
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Alert, FlatList, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import ItemList from '../../components/item-list/ItemList';
import SearchBar from '../../components/search-bar/SearchBar';
import { useTheme } from '../../context/ThemeProvider';
import MyService from '../../services/MyService';
import Styles from './styles';

const HomeScreen = ({navigation}) => {

    const { theme } : any = useTheme();

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getDados();
    }, []);

    async function getDados() {
        try {
            const response = await MyyService.getAllDados();
            setFilteredData(response.data);
            setData(response.data);
        } catch {
            Alert.alert(
                'Erro',
                'Falha ao exibir dados!',
                [{text: 'OK'}]
            );
        }
    }

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={[Styles.container, {backgroundColor: theme.backgroundColor}]}>
            <SearchBar data={data} onFilter={ (newData ) => setFilteredData(newData) } />
            <FlatList
                data={filteredData}
                renderItem={({item}) => <ItemList item={item} navigation={navigation} />}
                keyExtractor={(item) => String(item.id)}
            />
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}

export default HomeScreen;

// Search
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';
import { TextInput, View } from 'react-native';
import Styles from './styles';
import { useTheme } from '../../context/ThemeProvider';

const SearchBar = ({data, onFilter}) => {

    const { theme } : any = useTheme();

    const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');
    
    const searchFilter = (text: string) => {
        if(text) {
            const newData = data.filter((item) => {
                return item.nome.toUpperCase().indexOf(text.toUpperCase()) > -1;
            });
            
            setSearchText(text);
            onFilter(newData);
            
        } else {
            setSearchText(text);
            onFilter(data)
        }
    }

    return(
        <View style={Styles.searchContainer}>
            <View style={[Styles.inputContainer, {backgroundColor: theme.search.container}]}>
                <Icon
                    name="search"
                    size={20}
                    style={Styles.searchIcon}
                    color={theme.search.placeholder}
                />
                <TextInput 
                    style={[Styles.input, {color: theme.search.textColor}]}
                    placeholder='Pesquise por nome'
                    placeholderTextColor={theme.search.placeholder}
                    value={searchText}
                    onChangeText={(text) => searchFilter(text)}
                />
            </View>
        </View>
    );

};

export default SearchBar;
```